# print variable using text() in jquery?

Tags: jquery

The value of the variable "val" is not displayed. Alternatively, it prints the variable name.

```
 var val="Some text";

 $("span").text(val);
```

**Result :**

```
 val
```

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in stacksnippet or http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: can you create a demo with the said problem?

Comment: better to debug variables with console.log()

Comment: Please show a working example of the problem. If you can, then there is a *major* bug in jQuery and/or Javascript.

Comment: my mistake. Its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correctly working

```js
var val = "Some text";
$("span").text(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```